# can't clone repository from openshift cloud through git clone

Tags: git, ssh, openshift, git-clone

I'm trying to git-clone a repo on redhat openshift cloud with ssh url, but the command hangs in the middle of the operation :

[image]

What could be the problem here ?

Comment: IIRC, RedHat OpenShift is a commercial service. Why don't you contact their support team?

Comment: since there is an openshift tag here, I thought somebody would already know that problem, + I'm just using their free service, + this could be rather a git problem, + your comment doesn't bring anythin useful to the subject of the post

Comment: The remote side is experiencing some problems with preparing the packed blob of objects (high I/O wait?). Likely, you'd better ask support what's going on on their side.

Comment: the support is unfortunately only for paid services